# How can i set the value for MuiPhone number and an onChange event?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How can I set the muiphone number to have a value and to trigger the onChange where I can send it with my handleSubmit?

```
                 <MuiPhoneNumber
                    fullWidth
                    name="phone"
                    label="Phone Number"
                    data-cy="user-phone"
                    defaultCountry={"ph"}
                    onChange={(e) => setPhone(e.target.value)}
                  />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explain in the doc example :

> Your handler for the onChange event should expect a string as parameter, where the value is that of the entered phone number. [doc
> link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui-phone-number#usage)

the onChange props return a string not an event so you just need to replace `onChange={(e) => setPhone(e.target.value)}` by `onChange={(e) => setPhone(e)}`

[image: Edit lively-platform-enwi9]